# Must declare the scalar variable "@CURRENTYEAR"

Tags: sql, variables

I am trying to execute the below query but it popping up error as

**Must declare the scalar variable "@CURRENTYEAR".**

```
    DECLARE @CNTR INT, @POS INT, @STARTYEAR INT, @ENDYEAR INT, @MINDAY INT
    SELECT
           @CURRENTYEAR = MIN([Year])
        , @STARTYEAR = MIN([Year])
        , @ENDYEAR = MAX([Year])
    FROM @Holidays

    WHILE @CURRENTYEAR <= @ENDYEAR
    BEGIN
        SELECT @CNTR = COUNT([Year])
        FROM @Holidays
        WHERE [Year] = @CURRENTYEAR

        SET @POS = 1

        WHILE @POS <= @CNTR
        BEGIN
            SELECT @MINDAY = MIN(DAY)
            FROM @Holidays
            WHERE
                [Year] = @CURRENTYEAR
                AND [Week] IS NULL

            UPDATE @Holidays
                SET [Week] = @POS
            WHERE
                [Year] = @CURRENTYEAR
                AND [Day] = @MINDAY

            SELECT @POS = @POS + 1
        END

        SELECT @CURRENTYEAR = @CURRENTYEAR + 1
    END
```

why the error is popping and how to fix it?

Comment: Try set the variables in different lines and with default values.

Comment: You never declare `@CURRENTYEAR` in the first line like all of the other variables.

Comment: Well, where do you declare the scalar variable `@CURRENTYEAR`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this on your first line:

```
DECLARE @CNTR INT, @POS INT, @STARTYEAR INT, @ENDYEAR INT, @MINDAY INT, @CURRENTYEAR INT
```